# How to keep controls visible

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I've embedded a YouTube video on my blog. I want the controls to be visible, i.e. I don't want them to disappear. I've set controls=2 and autohide=0 in the embed line, but the controls disappear after a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `autohide` parameter has been deprecated for HTML5 players.

See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autohide